# Program clogging up my RAM- but when I stop it via 'sudo service X stop' it says its not loaded

Tags: mongodb

Specifically I'm trying to uninstall mongodb because this is what I get after booting up, when I press htop.

[image: Because this is what I get after booting up, when I press htop]

I don't want or need mongodb anymore, I want to remove it. So I followed the instructions [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#uninstall-mongodb-community-edition).

I ran

```
sudo service mongod stop
```

and got `Failed to stop mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not loaded.`

I then ploughed on and did

```
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*
```

And got:

```
E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org*
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'mongodb-org*'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'mongodb-org*'
```

What should I do?

EDIT: As per a question I tried `sudo apt list --installed *mongo*` and the output is:

```
mongo-tools/bionic,now 3.6.3-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
mongodb/bionic,now 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
mongodb-clients/bionic,now 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
mongodb-server/bionic,now 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
mongodb-server-core/bionic,now 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

I also tried `dpkg -l | grep 'mongo'`

```
ii  mongo-tools                          3.6.3-0ubuntu1                              amd64        collection of tools for administering MongoDB servers
ii  mongodb                              1:3.6.3-0ubuntu1                            amd64        object/document-oriented database (metapackage)
ii  mongodb-clients                      1:3.6.3-0ubuntu1                            amd64        object/document-oriented database (client apps)
ii  mongodb-server                       1:3.6.3-0ubuntu1                            all          object/document-oriented database (managed server package)
ii  mongodb-server-core                  1:3.6.3-0ubuntu1                            amd64        object/document-oriented database (server binaries package)
```

Comment: Update the question with the output of `sudo apt list --installed *mongo*` or `dpkg -l | grep 'mongo'`?

Comment: Done. [padding ]

Comment: This may be an issue I stumbled across a while ago.  You could try installing mongodb, use the newly installed mongodb to stop the service, then uninstall it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the updated question there are no packages matching `mongodb-org*`. Uninstalling mongodb will probably be achieved by issuing

```
sudo apt purge mongodb*
```

Uninstalling mongo-tools

```
sudo apt purge mongo-tools
```